# Why response from Jsoup.connect.execute is null? when throwing IOException?

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

My code look like this:

When I try to invoke this method with incorrect url e.g. http://en.dddddddddssss.org/ execute throw exception and response is null. Why? How can I got http code in that situation?

```
public Document getDocumentFromUrl(String url) throws SiteBusinessException {
        Response response = null;
        try {
            response = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(Constans.TIMEOUT).ignoreHttpErrors(false).userAgent(Constans.USER_AGENT)
                    .ignoreContentType(Constans.IGNORE_CONTENT_TYPE).execute();
            return response.parse();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            LOGGER.warn("Cannot fetch site ]");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

EDIT

```
public Document getDocumentFromUrl(String url) throws SiteBusinessException {
        Response response = null;
        try {
            response = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(Constans.TIMEOUT).ignoreHttpErrors(false)
                    .userAgent(Constans.USER_AGENT).ignoreContentType(Constans.IGNORE_CONTENT_TYPE).execute();
            return response.parse();
        } catch (HttpStatusException hse) {
            LOGGER.warn("Cannot fetch site [url={}, statusMessage={}, statusCode={}]",
                    new Object[] { url, response != null ? response.statusMessage() : "<null>",
                            response != null ? String.valueOf(response.statusCode()) : "<null>" });
            throw new SiteBusinessException(response != null ? response.statusMessage() : "<null>",
                    String.valueOf(response != null ? response.statusCode() : "<null>"));

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            LOGGER.warn("IOException. Cannot fetch site [url={}, errorMessage={}]", url, ioe.getMessage());
            throw new SiteBusinessException("Not found");
        }
    }
```

And then I'm trying to call `http://localhost:8090/wrongaddress/`. Jboss return HTTP 404.

But my code return

```
Cannot fetch site [url=http://localhost:8090/wrongaddress/, statusMessage=<null>, statusCode=<null>]
```

EDIT

WORKING SOLUTION

```
try {
            response = Jsoup.connect(url).execute();
            return processDocument(response.parse(), url);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            LOGGER.warn("Malformed URL [url={}, message={}]", new Object[] { url, iae.getMessage() });
            throw new SiteBusinessException(iae.getMessage());
        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
            LOGGER.warn("Malformed URL [url={}, message={}]", new Object[] { url, mue.getMessage() });
            throw new SiteBusinessException(mue.getMessage());
        } catch (HttpStatusException hse) {
            LOGGER.warn("Cannot fetch site [url={}, statusMessage={}, statusCode={}]",
                    new Object[] { url, hse.getMessage(), hse.getStatusCode() });
            throw new SiteBusinessException(hse.getMessage(), hse.getStatusCode());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            LOGGER.warn("IOException. Cannot fetch site [url={}, errorMessage={}]", url, ioe.getMessage());
            throw new SiteBusinessException("Cannot fetch site");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't. You are catching the Exception and returning null by yourself. You can never throw an exception and return something at the same time.

There will be no HTTP code, since the host does not exist. HTTP codes are returned by the server. For example, the best known code is 404 (Not Found). When your browser shows 404, it is simply a HTTP/TCP packet send by the server to the client, that contains this code.

Comment: This null is doesn't metter. I was looking in debug mode.